# Recursion thinking method

Tags: java, recursion

I know that it is many recursion tutorials out there, but I need to be sure that my thought process is right.

```
1+1=2

0+1=1

1+10=11

2+10=12
```

or

```
2

1

1+10 = 11

2+10 = 12
```

Which one of them is the right thinking, according to the code?

```
public class recTest {
    //public static int v = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(test(2));
        //(System.out.println("---");
        //System.out.println(v);
    }

    public static int test (int n) {
        if (n == 0)
            return 10;
        else
            System.out.println(n);
            return test(n-1) + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need paper, pencil, eraser and debugger.  Only after such effort will you learn what is going on.

Comment: I don't think this question is answerable.  Like @ThingyWotsit said, you should use a debugger and/or paper and pencil to see how things work.  But how that translates into the "right thought process" is probably not the same for everyone.  And probably not the same for every piece of code; I likely do _not_ use the same kind of thought process for every recursive code I see.

Comment: All this function does is add n number of 1s together plus 10.
If n=5, then 1+1+1+1+1+10 = 15

Answer (score 1):

The second option, because it does this first:

```
System.out.println(n);
```

And then calls the recursive method.

So, the first time, it will just print the input parameter: `2`.

Comment: I think the question was "what is the right thinking", not "what will the program print out".

Answer (score 1):

Neither is correct, as far as I can tell.

The second is more correct due to where the println is, but 1+10 and 2+10 are not accurate since you will never add 2 to 10.

You really add 1 to the 11 that gets returned in the recursive call when you call `test(2)`.

So more accurately you have:

```
test(2) -> test(1) + 1 ->           11 + 1 -> 12
test(1) -> test(0) + 1 -> 10 + 1 -> 11
test(0) -> 10          -> 10
```

Or if we write it out with expansion it would look like:

```
test(2)
= test(1) + 1
= (test(0) + 1) + 1
= (10 + 1) + 1
= (11) + 1
= 12
```

Answer (score 1):

As I said in a comment, I don't think there's such as thing as "the right thinking".  But here's a way I hope is helpful:

```
main calls test(2)
> test(n=2) prints 2
> test(n=2) calls test(1) to compute test(n-1) + 1
> > test(n=1) prints 1
> > test(n=1) calls test(0) to compute test(n-1) + 1
> > > test(n=0) returns 10
> > test(n=1) uses 10 for test(0)
> > test(n=1) computes test(0) + 1 = 10 + 1 = 11
> > test(n=1) returns 11
> test(n=2) uses 11 for test(1)
> test(n=2) computes test(1) + 1 = 11 + 1 = 12
> test(n=2) returns 12
main uses 12 for test(2)
main prints 12
```

A bit verbose, but you can keep whatever parts help your thinking.  But note that, as Trevor said, it doesn't directly compute 10 + 2 anywhere.  Of course, mathematically, it works out the same, since + has commutative and associative properties that mean that it doesn't matter what order you add a bunch of things in.

Answer (score 0):

I agree to @ThingyWotsit, but just to provide you with a simple reference, the process would be something like this(mathematical pseudo code):

```
sysout(test(2));
// test(2) prints: 2

sysout(test(1) + 1);
// test(1) prints: 1

sysout(test(0) + 1 + 1);
sysout(10 + 1 + 1);
sysout(12);
// prints: 12
```

You should really look into call stack principle.